# Plot vectors of gradient descent in R

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I've code gradient descent algorithm in R and now I'm trying to "draw" the path of the vectors.

I've got draw points in my contour plot, but it's not correct because nobody knows what happened first.

In my algorith always I have an previous state P=(Xi,Yi) and a later state L=(Xi+1,Yi+1), so, How can I draw the vector PL in a `contour` or a `persp` plot?

I only got this with `contour`, where the red point is the convergence:

[image: contour]

The same for `persp`:

[image: persp]

Thanks all!

EDIT:

Graphics can be obtanined respectively:

```
f<-function(u,v){
  u*u*exp(2*v)+4*v*v*exp(-2*u)-4*u*v*exp(v-u)
}

x = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.5)
y = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.5)
z <- outer(x,y,f)
#Contour plot
contour(x,y,z)
#Persp plot
persp(x, y, z, phi = 25, theta = 55, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2),
      xlab = "U", ylab = "V",
      main = "F(u,v)", col="yellow", ticktype = "detailed"
) -> res
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to connect the points to show the "iteration sequence"?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. This is my purpose.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we have something to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, Roman, here you have some code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking [Himmelblau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmelblau%27s_function) as a test example:

```
f <- function(x, y) { (x^2+y-11)^2 + (x+y^2-7)^2 }
```

Its partial derivatives:

```
dx <- function(x,y) {4*x**3-4*x*y-42*x+4*x*y-14}
dy <- function(x,y) {4*y**3+2*x**2-26*y+4*x*y-22}
```

Running the gradient descent:

```
# gradient descent parameters
num_iter <- 100
learning_rate <- 0.001
x_val <- 6
y_val <- 6

updates_x <- vector("numeric", length = num_iter)
updates_y <- vector("numeric", length = num_iter)
updates_z <- vector("numeric", length = num_iter)

# parameter updates
for (i in 1:num_iter) {

  dx_val = dx(x_val,y_val)
  dy_val = dy(x_val,y_val)

  x_val <- x_val-learning_rate*dx_val
  y_val <- y_val-learning_rate*dx_val
  z_val <- f(x_val, y_val)

  updates_x[i] <- x_val
  updates_y[i] <- y_val
  updates_z[i] <- z_val
}
```

Plotting:

```
x <- seq(-6, 6, length = 100)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, f)

plt <- persp(x, y, z,
               theta = -50-log(i), phi = 20+log(i),
               expand = 0.5,
               col = "lightblue", border = 'lightblue',
               axes = FALSE, box = FALSE,
               ltheta = 60, shade = 0.90
  )

points(trans3d(updates_x[1:i], updates_y[1:i], updates_z[1:i],pmat = plt),
       col = c(rep('white', num_iter-1), 'blue'),
       pch = 16,
       cex = c(rep(0.5, num_iter-1), 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to plotting points using persp, as mentioned in `?persp`. By employing the power of `trans3d`, you can successfully put points and lines on a perspective plot.

```
f<-function(u,v){
  u*u*exp(2*v)+4*v*v*exp(-2*u)-4*u*v*exp(v-u)
}

x = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.5)
y = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.5)
z <- scale(outer(x,y,f))

view <- persp(x, y, z, phi = 30, theta = 30, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2),
      xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z", scale = FALSE,
      main = "F(u,v)", col="yellow", ticktype = "detailed")

set.seed(2)
pts <- data.frame(x = sample(x, 3),
                  y = sample(y, 3),
                  z = sample(z, 3))

points(trans3d(x = pts$x, y = pts$y, z = pts$z, pmat = view), pch = 16)
lines(trans3d(x = pts$x, y = pts$y, z = pts$z, pmat = view))
```

[image]